# What part of speech is "care" in the following sentences?

Tags: nouns, prepositions, adjectives, compound-adjectives

> Joe is the student *with the highest grade*

*With the highest grade* is an adjective phrase modifying student, with "with" being a preposition and "highest" being the adjective.

But in the following sentence:

> He played baseball with great care

*With great care* is the adjective phrase, but I cannot figure out the head adjective: a) is it great or care? b) **great** could be a *degree adverb* describing the intensity of the adjective *care*. One could say *care* was noun, but if I changed it to:

> He played baseball w*ith care*

a) *Care* isn't a noun is it? The phrase "with care" is describing how the noun "baseball" is being played with.

Or if I were to make other sentences such as:

> He played baseball with the greatest care

In the above, there is less ambiguity (greatest) is the superlative form - so this must be the head adjective while care could be construed as noun because it has a determiner, ***the***.

Of course, if I removed *greatest*:

> He played baseball with the care...

Then "with the care" wouldn't make sense unless I added more things in it, such as:

> He played baseball with the care one would pay his grandmother

Comment: *With great care* is an ***adverbial*** (not adjectival) phrase, modifying the verb *played*. The "head" word is *care*, which could be approximated as the single-word adverb ***carefully***. Compare ***with joy, joyfully***. Also compare *I ate peas with rice* ("adjectival", if you like; modifies ***peas***) and *I ate dinner with her* (adverbial, modifies ***ate***).

Comment: "With" is a preposition, so "with the highest grade" is not an adjective phrase, but a preposition phrase modifying "student". And in "He played baseball with great care", "with great care" is a preposition phrase functioning as a manner adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ: adverbial and adjectivial phrases are types of *prepositional phrases*

Comment: @asking No, they are not. You are conflating category and function. A PP is a phrase with a preposition as head, which typically functions as an adjunct in clause structure or a modifier in NP structure. An adverb phrase has an adverb as head, e.g. "Quite separately from this issue" and an adjective phrase has an adjective as head, e.g. "very eager for more news".

Comment: According to the [University of Illinois](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/prepphrases/) they are. Doing a quick Google search brought me to where the OP quoted his example from.

Comment: @asking They are wrong as any serious grammarian will tell you.

Comment: Look: "with great care" is a PP functioning not as an adjective phrase, but as a modifier. To call it an adjective phrase is simply ridiculous. Within the PP, "with" has the NP "great care" as its complement. The PP as a whole describes how the referent of "he" played football, and is thus a manner adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ I don't disagree with you there but you said "with the highest grade" is not an adjective phrase to student(Joe)

Answer (score 1):

"Care" is a noun in all of the sentences that you mention, whether or not it has "the" before it. Many nouns in English can be used without an article: the most obvious examples are "mass nouns", like *water, wood, wind,* but there are also abstract nouns like *advice* or *information.* Another noun that behaves somewhat similarly to *care* is *concern*: we frequently use the phrase "with concern" with no article.

Prepositions like "with" generally don't take adjectives or adjective phrases as complements. Note that we can say things like "He played baseball with (great) passion", but not things like "*He played baseball with great passionate".

I can't even think of any context where "care" would be an adjective. It can be a noun or a verb.

Comment: You could have he was *caring*, but then that's just a present participle and not the same as "care". Or in *with the greatest care of affection* is care still a noun?

Comment: @aesking: "with the greatest care of affection" looks strange to me. If I heard it spoken, I would probably think the speaker had said "with the greatest care **and** affection", which seems a much more probable phrase to me. But in either case, "care" would be a noun.

Comment: Yes the use is quite unheard of in utterances and is more typically found in formal, outdated prose but not improbable. Some would say "care" is an attributive modifier; see [similar](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/SIEG/exx_ch5.html). Especially of abstract words such as *natural* (e.g. He was a natural vs It was a natural thing to do) and *human*.

Comment: @sumelic if adjectivals count, maybe **care** _package_...

Comment: I think "the greatest care of affection" is a fixed modifier head but I'm not sure. @Jas "Care package" is a compounded noun, with care being nominalised as a modifier/noun.

Comment: @aesking Interesting to think of _care_ in "care package" as a verb being nominalized—I've always taken it in the abstract noun sense, used as an adjectival to modify the noun _package_.

Comment: @Jas I didn't say it was a verb but it also has a *noun form* (noun being nominalised as an adjective)--depending on how you look at it.

Comment: It's actually CARE: Cooperative for Assistance and Relief Everywhere, formerly Cooperative for American Remittances to Europe.

Comment: I think that’s a rather specific and formal use of the term. When I give a friend a care package for when they are ill in hospital, I don’t necessarily mean “Cooperative for American Remittances to Europe”.